# Adding dynamic filter to tableWidget with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

How do I add a dynamic filter to a tableWidget with PyQGIS?

I would like the user to be able to gradually filter the row displayed in the tableWidget based on the text written in the lineEdit above it.

[image: before]
[image: after]

I have found several examples in stackoverflow with QSortFilterProxyModel but I can't find this function in PyQGIS

I'm a beginner in programming.

```
  def filter(self):

    with open('C:/path/myfile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")

        data = []
        model = QStandardItemModel()


        for row in file:
            data.append(row)
            data = list(filter(lambda k: self.dlg.mLineEdit.text() in k, data))

            items = [
                QStandardItem(field)
                for field in row]

            model.appendRow(items)

            nb_row = len(data)
            nb_col = len(data[0])
            self.dlg.tableWidget.setRowCount(nb_row)
            self.dlg.tableWidget.setColumnCount(nb_col)
            for row in range(nb_row):
                for col in range(nb_col):
                    item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
                    self.dlg.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, item)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit, but it seems to be the code you begin to wrote to filter your tableWidget. Can you share the code that fill and show the tableWidget please ?

Comment: I've changed my code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can tell you got some concepts a bit mixed up and you should probably read up on the difference between using [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) and [`QTableWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html). You got parts from both approaches mixed up in your code example.

##### 1. `QTableView`

With a `QTableView` you can use the [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to filter items. This will be the recommended approach which is elegant and scales well. On the downside, I find that the concepts are a bit harder to grasp for a beginner. I have put together an example using `QTableView`, which can be pasted and run from within QGIS script editor:

```py
class MyWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.edit = QLineEdit()
        self.edit.textChanged.connect(self.filter)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        
        data = [
            ('France', 'Paris'),
            ('United Kingdom', 'London'),
            ('Italy', 'Rome'),
            ('Germany', 'Berlin')
        ]
        
        self.tableView = QTableView()
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(4, 2)
        for row in range(4):
            for column in range(2):
                item = QStandardItem(data[row][column])
                self.model.setItem(row, column, item)
                
        self.proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self.tableView)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
            
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def filter(self, filter_text):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterFixedString(filter_text)
                
dlg = MyWindow(iface.mainWindow())
dlg.show()
```

##### 2. `QTableWidget`

`QTableWidget` doesn't provide a native solution for filtering items so what you can do instead is implement your own filter function which iterates through all of your `QTableWidgetItem` objects, determines if their text matches the filter and then hides or shows the row accordingly.

```py
class MyWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.edit = QLineEdit()
        self.edit.textChanged.connect(self.filter)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        
        data = [
            ('France', 'Paris'),
            ('United Kingdom', 'London'),
            ('Italy', 'Rome'),
            ('Germany', 'Berlin')
        ]
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4) 
  
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Country', 'Capital'])
  
        for row in range(4):
            for column in range(2):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(data[row][column])
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
        
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QHeaderView.Stretch)
            
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def filter(self, filter_text):
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(i, j)
                match = filter_text.lower() not in item.text().lower()
                self.tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, match)
                if not match:
                    break
                
dlg = MyWindow(iface.mainWindow())
dlg.show()
```

This will be the result no matter which approach you are deciding to use:
[image: gif]

Comment: Thanks CodeBard, the second part of your answer was what I needed. I'm still a bit confused about the differences between tableView and tableWidget so I will read up the links you have recommended